# swift firebase queryStartingAtValue

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase and am trying to search the title of the product using **queryStartingAtValue**.
in my firebase JSON and code below, I have a few levels to travel.
it look like -> /item/(section name: clothing,games etc)/autoID/(product name, price)
I was able to receive the results using for-loops all the way down until finding the specific string but it doesn't look good. I was wondering if **queryStartingAtValue** can shorten the trips looping through a child within the child or at least how to properly use **queryStartingAtValue**
much appreciated for help!! thanks

SWIFT

```
Database.database().reference().child("item").queryStarting(atValue:"Adidas").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            
            for snap in snapshot.children {
                if let snap = snap as? DataSnapshot {
                    if let childItem = snap.value! as? [String: Any] {
                        for key in childItem {
                           if let item = key.value as? [String: Any] {
                             if let title = item["Title"] as? String {
                               if title.contains("adidas") {
                                   print("found")
                               }
                             }
                           } 
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Firebase JSON

```
{
  "item": {
    "Clothing": {
      "-NFrGoNiI4zX-QBgEwkf": {
        "Price": 345,
        "Title": "Adidas",
        "availableQty": "100"
      }
    },
    "Games": {
      "-NFrGdmdV4FOBI34EnOW": {
        "Price": 199,
        "Title": "Overwatch Platinum Pack",
        "availableQty": "100"
      },
      "-NGL4vk1GC80ojMgZNik": {
        "Price": 66,
        "Title": "Overwatch 2",
        "availableQty": "100"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries consist of two steps:

1. First you order the child nodes on their key, their value or a child property.
2. Then you take a slice of that data by using `startAt`/`endAt`/`startAfter`/`endAfter`/`equalTo`.

Your code contains #2, but it does not contain any ordering instruction, which means that the database orders the nodes on their keys.

You'll instead want to include an instruction to order on the `Title`  child property:

```
Database.database().reference()
  .child("item")
  .queryOrdered(byChild: "Title") // 
  .queryStarting(atValue:"Adidas")
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
```

Comment: Hi Frank! this is great! I was able to search by adding another child after .child("item"). which is .child("Clothing") with your solution. is there a way to jump the "Clothing" part?

Comment: NVM! I got it, Thank you!!!!  if let snap = snap as? DataSnapshot {
                    let q = snap.ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "Title").queryStarting(atValue: titleName).queryEnding(atValue: "\(titleName)\\uf8ff")
                    q.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snaps in
                        print(snaps.value)
                    }
                    
                }

Answer (score -1):

if you need to powerfull search engine for firebase-ecommerce-app, you can use Algolia

1. Take a free plan to algolia
2. Algolia with firebase cloud-function (very easy!)
   [article algolia and cloud function](https://blog.expo.dev/update-using-algolia-and-firebase-cloud-functions-2b366089a75a)
3. Algolia with swift
   [algolia-swift](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/install/swift/?client=swift#test-your-installation)